# Why sbt-jsHint is not executing on "sbt jshint" command?

Tags: sbt, jshint, sbt-plugin

I am using sbt-jsHint plugin by typeFace: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jshint

Followed the steps as mentioned in the document, but could not the run the "sbt jshint" and getting invalid command error in sbt console.

Question:
1. What is best way to run the jsHint using sbt?

Tried another sbt-jslint plugin and did not work for me

Thanks,
Sandeep